# Swift - Firebase 4 - Proper method to handle remoteMessage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Everything was working good in Firebase v3.
I recently upgraded to Firebase v4.
I implemented all the protocol functions.

Stil Received msg is not handled and I get below warning

> [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002019] FIRMessaging received data-message, but FIRMessagingDelegate's-messaging:didReceiveMessage: not implemented

```
func application(appPsgVar: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    let remoteMessage = userInfo
    print("Forground : remoteMessage : \(remoteMessage)")
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(remoteMessage)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    let remoteMessage = userInfo
    print("Background : remoteMessage : \(remoteMessage)")
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(remoteMessage)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
}

// Fcm Message Received Handler Functions :

func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)
{
    // What message comes here?

    print("remoteMessage.appData : ", remoteMessage.appData)

}

// older way

func application(remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)
{
    print("remoteMessage.appData : ", remoteMessage.appData)
}

// Fcm Message protocol Functions :

func messaging(messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)
{
    print("New FCM Token received : \(fcmToken)")

}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func messaging(messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)
{
    // What message comes here ?


    print("remoteMessage.appData : ", remoteMessage.appData)

}
```

|*| If I try to implement this method its says :

```
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)
{
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
}
```

> Objective-C method 'applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:' provided by method 'applicationReceivedRemoteMessage' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(received:)' in protocol 'MessagingDelegate'

Kindly let me know which is the new correct method